# RobustScaler from scikit-learn not behaving properly

Tags: dataframe, scikit-learn, scale

I wanted to fit and cut the outliers part from my data, so I used RobustScaler (with data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/wkirgsn/electric-motor-temperature)) :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

scaler = RobustScaler(quantile_range = (25.0, 75.0))
df_robust = scaler.fit_transform(df) 
df_robust = pd.DataFrame(df_robust,columns=df.columns)
```

But when I plot the box plot,

```
df_robust.boxplot(figsize=(25,25))
plt.show()
```

it is clear that some data outside the quantile range are still there : [image: boxplot]

Have you already encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

RobustScaler does not remove outliers. When fitted, it computes a scale and mean that's robust to outliers. Outliers however would later be transformed like all other points using those parameters.

In other words, RobustScaler preserves outliers and tries to not let them influence the scaling of the non-outliers.

From the doc:

> This Scaler removes the median and scales the data according to the quantile range (defaults to IQR: Interquartile Range).

So what it does is compute something like this:

```
iqr = np.nanpercentile(xs, 75) - np.nanpercentile(xs, 25)
median = xs.median()
```

and standardize like this (check the source code for exact proportionality constant):

```
(xs - median) / iqr
```

There is no step that removes outliers.